# Defining a function in Pandas

Tags: pandas, function, dataset

I am new to Pandas and I am taking this course online. I know there is a way to define a function to make this code cleaner but I'm not sure how to go about it.

```
noshow = len((df[
    (df['Gender'] == 'M') \
    & (df['No_show'] == 'Yes') \
    & (df['Persons_age'] == 'Child')
]))

noshow
```

There is multiple Genders and multiple No_show answers and Multiple Person's age and I don't want to have write out the code for each one of those.

I've gotten the code for a single function but not for the mutiple iterations.

```
def print_noshow_percentage(column_name, value, percentage_text):
    total = (df[column_name] == value).sum()
    noshow = len((df[(df[column_name] == value) & (df['No_show'] == 'Yes')]))
    print(int((noshow / total) * 100), percentage_text)
```

I hope this makes sense. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your output is not clear. Do you need `df.groupby(['Gender', 'Persons_age']).No_show.value_counts(normalize=True)*100`?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Exchange. You are not too clear about your desired output, but I think what you are trying to do is to get a summary of every possible combination of age, gender, and no_show in your `df`. To accomplish this you can use the built in `groupby` method of pandas [documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

As mentioned by @ALollz, the following code will get you everything you need to know about your counts in terms of percentages.

```
counts = df.groupby(['Gender', 'Persons_age'])['No_show'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Now you need to decide what to do with it. You can either iterate through the dataframe printing each line, or you can find specific combinations or you can print out the whole thing.

In general, it is better to look for a built in method than to try to build a function outside of pandas. There are a lot of different ways to do things and checking the documentation is a good place to start.